# Control to Validate not find the id

Tags: asp.net

```
<input id="x_card_num" name="x_card_num" type="text" value="<%: CreditCardNumber %>"required="required" maxlength="16" />

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="x_card_num" ValidationExpression="/^[0-9]{16}/" ErrorMessage="invalid Card Number" ID="RegExCardnumber">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

When I use this regular expression, I am getting the error:

> controltoValidate id not found.

Comment: Here's the Wiki for regular expressions http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: That's not a regular expression...

Answer (score 1):

Error message said it all. You need to assign **ControlToValidate** like this -

```
<asp:TextBox ID="EmailTextBox" runat="server" ... />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="EmailTextBox" ... />
```

### Update for last added code

If you want to validate regular HTML control, you need `runat="server"`.

```
<input ... runat="server" />
```